# Interpreting lm-sensors output

Tags: hardware, monitoring, lm-sensors, psensor

First is my wifi module, second my SSD, third my CPU with individual cores, but what is the last one: "pch_skylake-virtual-0"?

[image: sensors]

Answer (score 5):

`pch_skylake-virtual-0` is the chipset on your motherboard ... `pch` is abbreviation from [Platform Controller Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub) ... `skylake` is the platform generation [code-name by Intel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_codenames) ... It's just the chipset.